# Mercurial - Merge Tracking branches in a development branch range

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial - Merge Tracking branches in a development branch range.

Hi, I have a Mercurial repository.

Would you like to command to return the branchs that have been merged into a development branch interval, ie something like this:
hg XXX Develop -b -r 5000..1000
result:
Branchs: X12, X13, X200

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the possibilities of the Mercurial `revsets` domain specific language:

```
hg help revsets
```

For instance, if you want to print only the changesets of branch `"default"` which are merges, you would specify `"merge() and ancestors('default')"`. Now you can ask for the parents of these merges (`"parents(...)"`), take out any changeset that is on `"default"` itself (`"and not branch('default')"`), and finally you can use templating to only print these changesets' branch name (`"--template '{branch}\n'"`), which gives something like:

```
$ hg log -r "parents(merge() and ancestors('default'))
  and not branch('default')" --template '{branch}\n'
X12
X13
[...]
```

The possibilities of the `revsets` DSL are pretty amazing.. :)

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Amazing, did not know of the possibility of using revsets, bringing my context, looks like this:
`code`
hg log -r "parents(merge() and branch('Desenv') and descendants(5000) and ancestors(1000)) and not branch('Desenv')" --template {branch}\n
`code`
I specified only to catch the merge of the development branch

Comment: In fact I needed to bring the review, then to solve this was done as follows:
'
branch ((parents (merge () and branch ('Development') and descendants (5000) and Ancestors (1000)) and not branch ('Development'))) or (branch ('Development') and descendants (5000) and Ancestors (1000)) '